# The "CompileAppManifest" task was not given a value for the required parameter "DefaultSdkVersion"

Tags: ios, iphone, maui

I am trying to test my .Net MAUI app on my iPhone on PC Visual Studio 2022 that is paired to a Mac with xCode and everything installed. My iPhone is connected to Mac, and I am trying to deploy to it as an iOS Remote Device.

The build fails with the following error:

error MSB4044: The "CompileAppManifest" task was not given a value for the required parameter "DefaultSdkVersion".

The error happens in Xamarin.Shared.targets:

```
<CompileSceneKitAssets
        SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)"
        AppBundleName="$(_AppBundleName)$(AppBundleExtension)"
        Condition="'$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true'"
        ToolExe="$(CopySceneKitAssetsExe)"
        ToolPath="$(CopySceneKitAssetsPath)"
        SceneKitAssets="@(SceneKitAsset)"
        IntermediateOutputPath="$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(_ComputedTargetFrameworkMoniker)"
        ProjectDir="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
        ResourcePrefix="$(_ResourcePrefix)"
        IsWatchApp="$(IsWatchApp)"
        SdkPlatform="$(_SdkPlatform)"
        SdkDevPath="$(_SdkDevPath)"
        SdkRoot="$(_SdkRoot)"
        SdkVersion="$(_SdkVersion)">
        <Output TaskParameter="BundleResources" ItemName="_BundleResourceWithLogicalName" />
```

Deleting bin and obj folder does not help.

The app runs successfully on simulators.

What is missing?

Comment: You say, "My iPhone is connected to a Mac and I'm trying to deploy it as an iOS remote device." Do you create and manage signing identities, app IDs, and provisioning profiles via auto/manual provisioning? Yes Refer to the official document: [Device provisioning for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT For some reason, the error is just gone. Can't explain it. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT And now the issue is back...

Comment: When your error disappears, you can deploy and run the application on the iPhone, right? Then this problem occurs again. Did you do anything during this process?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Actually, the error doesn't disappear. When I build the solution, the error is there. But when I ignore it and just run the debugging, the app is installed, but does not open, being stuck at "InstallComplete - PercentComplete: 100%. Application bundle 'com.something.Something' installed on 'My iPhone'". On a simulator, the app opens without problem.

Comment: After that the build cannot be stopped, and the only way is to kill the Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm having this same issue when I do a "Rebuild" but if I do a "Build" it doesn't happen. 

.NET 7 MAUI on Visual Studio 17.5.2

Comment: @RyanWatson Yes, I just tried it, and could build successfully. Not sure if this can be considered a solution, as I still don't know the root cause of the issue... But thank you!

Comment: @DavidShochet yeah I don’t think I would consider it a solution but like you I am using this as a workaround until figuring out what is actually going on.  It is frustrating, that’s for sure.

Comment: Doing a "rebuild" will give you problems, doing a "build" will work fine, you can report the problem to Visual Studio, and in the meantime, you can use this as a temporary solution.

Comment: @RyanWatson Please make this an answer, and I will mark it. It is a way to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a "Build" instead of a "Rebuild" will get the error to go away.  Not a fix but at least a workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but with an iPad.

Steps to "Fix":

1. Disconnect the device.
2. Wait for the target device to change to "Remote Device".
3. Plug the device back in.
4. Wait for the target device to change back to "xxx's iPad"

*After this, I got "error MT1007: Failed to launch the application", but then it deployed properly.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, in my case this does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

For me removing of `/bin` and `/obj` folder did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I tried all, delete bin and obj, build vs rebuild.
This seems to have worked: (my Macbook was not paired, so be sure it's paired), then after I paired my Mac, I still had problems, but I disconnected and reconnected my iPhone and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to @RyanWatson, Change "Rebuild" to "Build" and it will work without errors.