Can't distribute MAUI iOS App to app store VS2022 The "CompileAppManifest" task was not given a value for the required parameter "DefaultSdkVersion"
We have written an MAUI App in VS2022 Windows (.NET 8) - it complies, works fine on iOS and Android simulators. It has deployed successfully to the Google Play store. But we cannot get it to deploy to the iOS store. The app bundle is created successfully, but at the point where we try to deploy it we get the error:

Could not create ipa file for distribution of the archive '' The "CompileAppManifest" task was not given a value for the
required parameter "DefaultSDKVersion".


I believe this issue is relating to a problem with the project editor. Under iOS -> Build -> SDK version, the dropdown list is EMPTY, so I cannot choose an SDK version.

Manually adding the DefaultSdkVersion key to the appropriate PropertyGroup makes no difference.

Can anyone please help resolve this issue?
Thank you
We have tried:

Cleaning and rebuilding the app
Deleting the Obj and Bin folders and rebuilding
Disconnecting and reconnecting to the iMac used for building
Various configuration tweaks.

We expect things to work as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs
None of the suggestions at: The "CompileAppManifest" task was not given a value for the required parameter "DefaultSdkVersion" have resolved the issue.
We are running the latest version of xCode on the build iMac, and the latest (non preview) version of Vs2022.

I do not have such thing in my project.

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812008/833395

Thank you, as I mentioned above, nothing in that other Stack Overflow question works. The scenario is different.

For anyone else struggling with this problem, this Visual Studio error message is very misleading and unhelpful, as it doesn't identify the actual problem:

Could not create ipa file for distribution of the archive ‘’ The
“CompileAppManifest” task was not given a value for the required
parameter “DefaultSDKVersion”.

To fix the underlying problem you need to let the MAUI your_project.csproj project file control everything (especially to do with versions).
FIRSTLY: Remove specific settings from the Platforms > iOS > Info.plist file to do with versions (even if they match the main project file). Check you have removed MinimumOSVersion, CFBundleShortVersionString, CFBundleVersion and CFBundleIdentifier from the Platforms > iOS > Info.plist file
The reason for these problems is that the msbuild file (DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!) in "Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8053\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets" still doesn't quite have correct logic for handling overriding the csproj file settings from the Platforms > iOS > Info.plist file. Everything works fine for dev testing on simulators, building for release and publishing for release, but it will fall over when you try to "Distribute".
SECONDLY: Remove or amend any reference to versions in the MAUI csproj file (right click on the project --> Edit Project File)
Make sure the following are included and ALL MATCH, and that the ApplicationDisplayVersion has at least a x.x format. ApplicationVersion and Version should be a whole number.
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android34.0;net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- OTHER STUFF HERE -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>22.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>22</ApplicationVersion>
    <Version>22</Version>
        <!-- OTHER STUFF HERE -->
<PropertyGroup>

It is also best to allow icons etc. to all be controlled from the csproj file.
As an added bonus, "Distribute" still won't work on the latest release of Visual Studio (17.10.1), even if you fix the problem above, and get it to build the ipa file. The issue is fixed in 17.11.
It will fall over after you supply your AppleId and App Specific Password with the error:

Publishing project ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxx’ completed with errors. App Store
bundle validation failed for archive xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx The
“ALToolValidate” task was not given a value for the required parameter
“FilePath”.

Use your Mac build machine to deploy to the App Store:
Go to XCode -> Window -> Organizer -> Archives -> Distribute -> Submit to the App Store

This is my working configuration for distribution MAUI iOS from Windows

Remove DefaultSdkVersion from the solution
Note that I have a trick to publish after hundred failures:

Re-open Visual Studio (start a new session)
Connect to MAC from Visual Studio
Select Release Mode (Android net8.0-android)
Rebuild with Android
Change mode to iOS (net8.0-ios) Remote Device
Build with iOS (Don't Rebuild) it takes 10~15 mins (My CPU i7-4770)
Publish with iOS it takes 3~6 mins


Now you have 2 options after publish completed:

Open Visual Studio on MAC device

Create a new Maui project
Go to Archive you will find the ipa file, ready to be signed


Distribute from Windows and locate the file on windows


 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios'">
   <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
   <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
   
   <CodesignKey>Apple Distribution: Mustafa Alhadi (XXXXXXXXX)</CodesignKey>
   <CodesignProvision>XXXXXDistribution</CodesignProvision>
   
   <ArchiveOnBuild>true</ArchiveOnBuild>
 </PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
  <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  <WarningLevel>7</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Release')) And $(TargetFramework.Contains('ios'))">
  <MtouchInterpreter>-all,System.Collections.Immutable</MtouchInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>



Info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
  <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
  <string>My App</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.myapp.mustafa</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.34</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>34</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app uses camera for sending images with requests</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>



Thank you Mustafa - I very much appreciate you taking the time to give such a detailed answer. I am going to try your workaround now. If you are having the same problems as me, please vote here to get Microsoft to fix the problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-distribute-MAUI-iOS-App-to-app-sto/10671965

Welcome, hope it works, I voted there.

Great, thank you for voting. I've tried to follow your steps, but I don't have Visual Studio for Mac, I'm working on Windows, so I'm not sure how to proceed after the "publish" step. It still fails with the same error if I click "distribute".

Welcome, you don't really need Visual Studio for mac, I used that because I couldn't find the Archives folder, you can follow @user3096961 answer. please post your iOS plist file (open it by xml) I will post mine later.

Remove DefaultSdkVersion from your solution

Thank you for your help @Mustafa Mutasim, the problem is now solved, and you can see my answer below. The issue is that the error message is completely misleading and unhelpful.

For VS version 17.10 only - if the distribute to IOS fails, the archive may be on the paired mac.  Go to:

xcode
Window
Organizer
Archives
select your archive and click Distribute App
I read this bug is fixed with vs 17.11 (not yet available)


Thank you. The archive is only built at the point where the "Distribute" button is clicked. You are correct though, the steps above are necessary if you can get past the "Distribute" step because of another bug.
